# I need a reliable method to count the nbr of Resources

Tags: json, command-line, count, jq

I have the following JSON that comes back from an API:

```
{
"Statement": [{
        "Sid": "Group1",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:ecs:*:777744445555:task-rendition/${aws:PrincipalTag/Service}-*:*",
        "Effect": "Allow"
    },
    {
        "Sid": "Group2",
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:ecs:*:777744445555:task-definition/${aws:PrincipalTag/Service}-*:*",
            "arn:aws:ecs:*:777744445555:task-petition/${aws:PrincipalTag/Service}-*:*",
            "arn:aws:ecs:*:777744445555:task-fruition/${aws:PrincipalTag/Service}-*:*"
        ],
        "Effect": "Allow"
    }

]}
```

When I apply these commands I get unreliable results:

.Statement[0].Resource | length   -->  73 incorrect 
.Statement[1].Resource | length   -->  3 correct

The first command produces the number equal to the number of characters in that string, which is not what I need.  How can I achieve the 1 and 3 in a more certain way?

My context is bash shell script on CentOS 7 and jq 1.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `Resource` can either be of type `string` or `array`

```
.Statement[].Resource | if type == "array" then length else 1 end
```

will output

```
1
3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the `Resource` section to an array, flatten() it, then pipe it out to length() to get the correct number of elements.

```
$ cat api_return.json | jq '[.Statement[0].Resource] | flatten | length'
1
```

Answer (score 1):

For the total count of resources, wherever they are specified, you might like to consider:

```
def sigma(s): reduce s as $x (0; .+$x);

sigma(.. | objects | select(.Resource).Resource
      | if type == "array" then length else 1 end)
```